# Elegant alternatives for huge amount of arguments in class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, arguments

For example I have a class that builds the GUI, a class that handles all the events for the GUI and the main class that holds all the objects that are affected by the GUI-Objects (mostly sliders) and instances both the GUI-class and event-class.

Now the event-class's constructor has as arguments the GUI class and every object that is being changed by the GUI. These are quite allot of objects so the amount of arguments I have now are about 8 and still growing.

Is there a more elegant solution to my problem, 30 arguments simply doesn't feel right?

ps, I'd rather not combine classes because all three are quite big and would make everything much less readable.

Comment: Are all argument of same type? if yes then you can take an array of them.

Comment: Would a Hashmap work?  I would tend towards a xml configuration approach like spring, but that may not work for you

Comment: @Zoidberg , wouldn't that unnecessary complicate things?

Comment: I am just applying some of the tactics used in YUI where they use a configuration object to initialize classes that can have an exceptional amount of arguments.  If you use a hashmap it allows you to accept it into an init method which can pull the values out, type caste them and put them in instance variables.  I don't think it would add to much complication, and it would shorten your constructor's parameter count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a configuration class which holds default values for all parameters:

```
public class GUIConfig {

  private String name = "default";
  // more private declarations

  public GUIConfig() {
    // constructor, just for setting defaults
  }

  // getters and setters

}
```

Now you can simply create your GUI class instance like this:

```
GUIConfig guiConfig = new GUIConfig();
guiConfig.setName("foo");
// more setters
GUI myGUI = new GUI(guiConfig);
```

or for using only defaults:

```
GUI myGUI = new GUI(new GUIConfig());
```

Comment: Hmm, this would be a nice/simple solution indeed. Thanks!

Comment: You can enable fluent syntax by causing the setters to `return this;` at the end.  Then you can write: `GUI myGUI = new GUI(new GUIConfig().setName("foo"));` if you prefer.  Or just `guiConfig.setName("foo").setAddress("123 Bar Road").setCity("Fooville");`

Answer (score 12):

Often a builder object with fluent syntax is used in such a case.  You change:

```
new XYZEvent(a, null, null, b, null, c, d, null, null)
```

to

```
new XYZEventBuilder().setA(a).setB(b).setC(c).setD(d).build()
```

Comment: What is the advantage of such a approach?

Comment: @dasdasd: In a normal function or constructor call, parameters are differentiated by position only.  With a fluent syntax, parameters are given meaning by name, and the order is allowed to vary.  The builder object also allows the parameter list to be collected piecemeal, you can save it in a variable, set some properties, go parse a file, set some more properties, then finally call `build()`.

Comment: I can definitely see the advantage of that, but after searching a bit on google I can't find any examples of this tactic/object (in java). Any keywords I should be looking for?

Comment: Oh nvm, I found something. Thanks for this advice!

Comment: After looking more into it it seems that it's more useful if you need multiple 'flavours' of of the 'builded' class. Now I only want to configure the events class only once so I don't see any big advantages in building an EventBuilder-class if I only use it once against simply creating a configuration-class and use that as argument for the EventClass instead.

Comment: @Dasdasd: Note that I'm assuming that there's some step which can't be completed until all the options are known.  If all the work can be completed as each option is set, then the final "build" call can be removed.

Comment: @Dasdasd: The only difference between a builder object and @Alp's later answer is how the object is finally constructed.  In mine, the last line would read `GUI myGUI = guiConfig.build();`.  The fluent syntax is a separate issue from use of a builder class, and @Alp's configuration object would also benefit from using it.

Comment: @Dasdasd Ben Voigt's answer is better - there's no substantive difference between them, but it's neater for most cases because the gui class doesn't need to know about the config object in the builder pattern. The only reason you'd use the config approach over the builder approach is if your config object exists in some more substantive form i.e. a text file that can be downloaded or that the user can alter.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DTO ([Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) to hold all your classes. This can then be passed in a single parameter.

> a DTO does not have any behavior
>   except for storage and retrieval of
>   its own data

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Google's AutoValue library: https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Card {
    @Nullable 
    public abstract Integer localId();

    public abstract Long utcStart();

    public abstract Integer paramA();

    public abstract Integer paramB();

    @Nullable 
    public abstract Boolean paramC();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_Card.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setLocalId(final Integer localId);
        public abstract Builder setUtcStart(final Long utcStart);
        public abstract Builder setParamA(final Integer paramA);
        public abstract Builder setParamB(final Integer paramB);
        public abstract Builder setParamC(final Boolean paramC);
        public abstract Card build();
    }
}
```

All the no-mandatory fields can be annotated with `@Nullable`.

To create an immutable Card object you just use this:

```
Card myCard = Card.builder()
                .setLocalId(123456)  // this line can be omitted
                .setUtcStart(158632478000)
                .setParamA(5)
                .setParamB(58)
                .setParamC(true) // this line can be omitted
                .build();
```

"AutoValue is a great tool for eliminating the drudgery of writing mundane value classes in Java. It encapsulates much of the advice in Effective Java Chapter 2, and frees you to concentrate on the more interesting aspects of your program. The resulting program is likely to be shorter, clearer, and freer of bugs. Two thumbs up."

-- Joshua Bloch, author, Effective Java