# How to avoid making long constructors

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I have a client library in which I am making http remote calls to my rest service and then I am returning `List<DataResponse>` back to the customer who is calling our library with the response I am getting from my REST service along with any errors if there are any wrapped around `DataResponse` object.

```
public class DataResponse {

    private final String response;
    private final boolean isLink;
    private final TypeOfId idType;
    private final long ctime;
    private final long lmd;
    private final String maskInfo;

    // below are for error stuff
    private final ErrorCode error;
    private final StatusCode status;

    // constructors and getters here

}
```

Here is my `ErrorCode` enum class:

```
public enum ErrorCode {

    // enum values

    private final int code;
    private final String status;
    private final String description;

    // constructors and getters

}
```

And here is my `StatusCode` enum class:

```
public enum StatusCode {
    SUCCESS, FAILURE;
}
```

As you can see in my `DataResponse` class I have lot of fields so basis on that I have a very long constructor and everytime when I make a `DataResponse` object I have a big line with `new DataResponse(.......)`. In future I might have more fields but for now I only have these fields.

Is there any better way I can use to make a `DataResponse` object and then return back `List<DataResponse>` from my library?

Comment: You can use builder pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395981/3885376

Comment: I wouldn't depend on a builder yet. You have lots of fields? Sounds like a job for decomposition. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784390/object-oriented-design-how-important-is-encapsulation-when-therere-lots-of-da/33785266#33785266). If you still feel you are passing too much data to the constructor afterwards, then you could use a builder pattern. Although proper decomposition usually does the trick. I find builders to be useful for optional parameters (to avoid telescoping constructors which supply default values, rather than avoiding lots of parameters)

Comment: BUilderPattern is best to avoid long constructors or constructors havong two many parameters.

Comment: As too many parameters in constructors reduces readability of the code.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I might have some optional parameters here as well and some mandatory parameters.

Comment: @david If you have some optional and some mandatory parameter then you must have to use builder pattern

Comment: Adding a builder pattern is a Java best practice.

Comment: @AshishAni No, it's not for long parameters. It's best for optional parameters. If there are lots of parameters, it should be decomposed, as thats a sign that the type may have low cohesion.

Comment: You can find a lot of info from this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Given my current scenario how would I use decomposition here?

Comment: @VinceEmigh For long parameters we may have some mandatory and some no so mandatory parameters. We can use builder pattern

Comment: @VinceEmigh according to book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch builder pattern is best for these scenarios only.

Comment: @david Your identifiers are not descriptive enough for me to say. `lmd`, `ctime` and `maskinfo` have no meaning to me, but maybe they could be decomposed into a `ResponseDetails` object

Comment: @AshishAni I don't think you interpreted that chapter correctly. I have also read Effective Java, which uses nutrition info as an example for builders - some nutrition values are optional, thus the builder pattern was a good deign for that scenario

Comment: Repetitive discussion. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302891/the-builder-pattern-and-a-large-number-of-mandatory-parameters and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638722/how-to-improve-the-builder-pattern

Comment: @YoungHobbit Read my answer. It gives details as to why a builder pattern is bad for "lots of constructor parameters". I'm surprised so many people misunderstand the purpose of the pattern.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Do not use the [builder pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) right away.** It is not for types with tons of *required* fields. It's for types with tons of *optional* fields.

Builders' required properties are specified via the constructor. You are not forced to define values using methods, which makes those values optional.

*This leaves potential for your object being only partially constructed*. Using a builder for this would be abuse of the design.

---

With that said, you should [decompose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)) your type. I'm not sure what `lmd` or `ctime` is, or really what a `DataResponse` is supposed to represent, so I cannot tell you in which way you should decompose. But I can tell you [cohesion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) is what determines such.

`isLink`, `maskInfo` and `idType` could possibly be decomposed into a `DataResponseDetails` object:

```
class DataResponseDetails {
    private boolean isLink;
    private String maskInfo;
    private TypeOfId idType;

    public DataResponseDetails(boolean isLink, String maskInfo, TypeOfId idType) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now your `DataResponse` could be composed of `DataResponseDetails`:

```
class DataResponse {
    private DataResponseDetails details;
    private String response;
    //...

    public DataResponse(DataResponseDetails details, String response, ...) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Feel your constructor requires too much still? Decompose more!

Comment: I would add that, to me, it should be considered a best practice to use Optional class (the one from Guava or Java 8) for optional fields, to get rid of null values

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can identify smaller logical groups of fields an move them into objects of an own class. Then you can assemble all these objects in your `DataResponse` objects.

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua Bloch stated it in Item 2 of Effective Java 2nd Edition, you should consider using a builder pattern, as it is a best practice.

Here is what you code could look like using it :

```
 public class DataResponse {

        private final String response;
        private final boolean isLink;
        private final TypeOfId idType;
        private final long ctime;
        private final long lmd;
        private final String maskInfo;

        // below are for error stuff
        private final ErrorCode error;
        private final StatusCode status;

        // constructors and getters here


        public static class Builder {

            private final String response;
            private final boolean isLink;
            private final TypeOfId idType;
            private final long ctime;
            private final long lmd;
            private final String maskInfo;

            // below are for error stuff
            private final ErrorCode error;
            private final StatusCode status;

            public Builder reponse(final String response) {
                this.response = response;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder isLing(final boolean isLink) {
                this.isLink = isLink;
                return this;
            }

            public DataResponse builder() {
                return new DataResponse(this);
            }

            ...

        }

        private DataResponse(final Builder builder) {
            this.response = builder.response;
          this.isLink  = builder.isLink;
        }
    }
```

and then do something as follow :

```
DataResponse response = new DataResponse.Builder().reponse(anyResponse).isLink(isLink).build();
```